# PL/SQL query using multiple ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION statements

Tags: oracle, window-functions, row-number

I have a procedure to QA that contains multiple instances of the row_number() over partition structure as well as count(y) and sum(x) to calculate a range of metrics.  To QA this I have written a set a distinct queries that each perform one of the metric calculations.

The issue I am seeing is that my distinct queries are not always returning the same results as the procedure that I am testing.  Both my queries and the procedure source the same base table and the only difference is the fact that I have multiple, discrete, queries.

I seem to recall reading somewhere, and I have been unable to locate that source, that utilising multiple instances of row_number() over partition in a single query may generate "strange" results.

Is this correct?  Or have I miss-read something?

Cheers,

Gary

Comment: You may want to show the procedure?

Comment: And an example of how you're running the query separately, where you get a different result? It seems more likely that you're grouping or filtering differently, but a bug isn't impossible of course.

Comment: As written your question has no definite answer e.g. (we have no data to test against, no code to review or compare). You may want to visit [help] to consider how best to ask questions here. I have used multiple row_number() calculations in various Ora 11g instances without issue. Also note if you suspect a bug then we would also need to know the exact version of Oracle you are running.